# Change URL when requesting image attachement - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to make a wordpress plugin to generate compressed images 
and i need to know what's the hook or action i can use to replace 
image url with the compressed one when calling wp_get_attachment_image ,without the need to change them in database 
any ideas ??
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function alter_image_attributes($attr) {
  $attr['data-src'] = 'compressed_image_url';
  return $attr;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'alter_image_attributes');
```

Answer (score 0):

wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $size, $icon, $attr );

Manage the function parameters like.

$size = "thumbnail', 'medium' ,'full', 'any custom size defined'